# FATFS: How to get address of first sector of a file?

Tags: filesystems, stm32, disk, fatfs

I am using fatfs on stm32 and I want to find the address of first
sector of a file which is opened using f_open function. Thus I can
use that sector address to access the file as a address offset using
low level DMA methods available.
How can I get the raw address of the file on disk?

Answer (score 1):

In Chan's FatFS you can known the file starts cluster, it's in `fp->sclust` variable. You can know cluster size with this expression:`clusterSize = fp->fs->csize * SS(fp->fs);` and you can also need the funcion `clust2sect(fp->fs, fp->clust)`.
You can watch the implementation of `Diskio_drvTypeDef.disk_read` to see how to convert to adress.

Comment: Actually the files start cluster is in `fp->obj.sclust` as long as you haven't read from that file (otherwise its in `fp->clust`)